# FileHandle not accepting my URLs for write access

Tags: swift, cocoa, file-writing, filehandle

I'd like to open a uniquely named output file for writing either plist or data, but not having any luck in getting a handle using either URL routine of init(fileURLWithPath:) or init(string:)

```
func NewFileHandleForWritingFile(path: String, name: String, type: String, outFile: inout String?) -> FileHandle? {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    var file: String? = nil
    var uniqueNum = 0

    while true {
        let tag = (uniqueNum > 0 ? String(format: "-%d", uniqueNum) : "")
        let unique = String(format: "%@%@.%@", name, tag, type)
        file = String(format: "%@/%@", path, unique)
        if false == fm.fileExists(atPath: file!) { break }

        // Try another tag.
        uniqueNum += 1;
    }

    outFile = file!

    do {
         let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: file!)
        let fileHandle = try FileHandle.init(forWritingTo: fileURL)
        print("\(file!) was opened for writing")
        //set the file extension hidden attribute to YES
        try fm.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey.extensionHidden: true], ofItemAtPath: file!)
        return fileHandle
    } catch let error {
        NSApp.presentError(error)
        return nil;
    }
}
```

debugger shows

[image: debugger shows]

which for this URL init routine adds the scheme (file://) but otherwise the same as the other, and I'd like to prefer the newer methods which throw reutrning (-1) when just using paths. The error thrown (2) is an ENOENT (no such entity!?) as I need a handle to **write to** I'm confused how else to get one?  The sample path is a new folder created at desktop to triage.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the previous answer, I recommend using Data's `write(to:options:)` API instead of FileManager's `createFile(atPath:contents:attributes:)`, because it is a URL-based API, which is generally to be preferred over path-based ones. The Data method also throws an error instead of just returning false if it fails, so if something goes wrong, you can tell the user why.

`try Data().write(to: fileURL, options: [])`

I would also suggesting replacing the path-based `FileManager.fileExists(atPath:)` with the URL-based `checkResourceIsReachable()`:

`if false == ((try? fileURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false)`

Comment: Well I was still on the fence vs. writing data or a plist, but I'll keep this in mind, thanks!

Comment: I ended up creating a variant function that returns a url for writing so I can use the suggested data write method: `try data.write(to: fileURL)`

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a file handle to a non-existent file. That is what is causing the ENOENT error.

Use `FileManager createFile(atPath:contents:attributes:)` to create the file just before creating the file handle.

```
do {
    fm.createFile(atPath: file!, contents: nil, attributes: [FileAttributeKey.extensionHidden: true])
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: file!)
    let fileHandle = try FileHandle(forWritingTo: fileURL)
    print("\(file!) was opened for writing")

    return fileHandle
} catch let error {
    NSApp.presentError(error)
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: You're a life saver. I spent hours trying to write some files (from a custom background queue) which failed for `data.write(to:)` and the `FileHandle` API but worked with the `manager.createFile` API. Are there any docs that confirm your statement that a file must be created first before writing the data? I have a different code snippet on the main queue which just works out of the box without `manager.createFile` API. This is truly a confusing behavior.

Comment: @DevAndArtist It's in the documentation for `FileHandle init?(forWritingTo: String)`: *"The initialized file handle object or nil if no file exists at path."*.